# How to combine multiple signals into a composite slot in PyQt?

Tags: concurrency, pyqt5, signals-slots

The problem described in the top diagram: the reader reads an image `a` and two objects P1 and P2 have to process this image data. The processing in P2 involves both the original image `a` and the output of P1: `b`. Both P1 and P2 extend QWidget and the methods are slots: `P1.process(a)` and `P2.process(a, b)`.

[image: Top:the problem. Bottom: attempted solution]

In an ideal world, I would want to have a way to connect two signals, `a` from `Reader` and `b` from `P1` connect to the two *parameters* of the slot (I am thinking of something similar to LabView). But it looks like Qt signals and slot connections do not allow that.

As an workaround I created a dummy class as an intermediary where input to `slot_a` just stores the input value in `dummy._a` attribute and input to `slot_b` sends out a signal with two args, `(dummy._a, b)` and this is received by `P2.slot_ab(a, b)` which finished the processing in P2.

But apparently there is no easy way to ensure that `Dummy.slot_a` will be called before `Dummy.slot_b`, so the value of `a` may not get initialized, or be stale.

What will be a good and simple way to pass `a` and the corresponding value of `b` to P2 and trigger its processing?

I am using pyqt5 for this.

Comment: Since `P1` also recieves the original image, couldn't you send that with the signal from `P1` as well together with the processed image?

Comment: @Heike Yes, that is a solution I did consider. But in the real problem I have, many processing objects like P1 which are pipelined to carry out different steps on the image and take just a single image. I do not like the idea of forcing a redundant parameter on all of them to accommodate this (which is a single unusual case).